# React Apollo SSR and get query result

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Is it possible to get graphql query data on SSR side when constructing tree, before to be sent on the client ?
The renderToString() method render the entire tree without data, i am wondering if it exist a method to fetch data from graphql before rendering to client and handle these data on SSR side or not

Answer (score 0):

I think `renderToStringWithData` function which described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/server-side-rendering/) should resolve your problem.

Feel free to comment if you need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Apollo, you have a very handy helper that will trigger any query found on the constructed react tree while performing SSR : [getDataFromTree](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/server-side-rendering/#using-getdatafromtree)

The whole page is worth reading if you try to implement SSR with Apollo graphQL.